# Prettier - how to move template tag in Python to new line?

Tags: python, html, prettier

I've installed prettier extension in the VS code.
Before formatting:

```
<form action="{% url 'home:index' %}" method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ form_email.as_div }}
  {{ form_message.as_div }}
  <button name="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

After formatting, the template tags are on the same line but each should be moved to new line:

```
<form action="{% url 'home:index' %}" method="post">
  {% csrf_token %} {{ form_email.as_div }} {{ form_message.as_div }}
  <button name="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

Is it possible to tell prettier how to handle template tags coming form python syntax?